# How is it possible to change field "created" in docker image?

Tags: docker, image, timestamp

I have a docker image (FIRST) with correct field "created"

Then I make a manipulation with it, correct some fields using another docker image (SECOND)

And when I use docker inspect I see that field "created" is "Created": "1980-01-01T00:00:01Z",

created 44 years ago, of course it is false

SECOND image was builded by me, it was FROM docker:latest (standarted) and I copied from local some needed files inside the container

So, how can I change field created? Why there is no timestamp anymore?

Described in problem details

SECOND dockerfile

FROM docker:latest

COPY /usr(*I unpacked .deb file in local dir*) /usr

Comment: Do you have the Dockerfile that creates the second image?

Comment: yes, added in question description